# Can't receive data from button Listener

Tags: java, android, button, android-alertdialog

I want to make button when I click on it a dialog appears and I read data from that dialog. In the dialog I have only EditText for data. My data is numbers. 
Here is my code:

```
Button mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReportActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_for_percent , null);
                EditText savingsDialog = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.percentEditText);
                mBuilder.setView(mView)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.done, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
                //if (savingsDialog.getText().toString().length() > 0) { I tried this if, but I receive empty data
                    SharedPreferences savings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savings.edit();
                    editor.putString("percent", savingsDialog.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();

                    updateSavingsView(Integer.parseInt(savingsDialog.getText().toString()));// here I want to put my data in method which update my TextView
                //}
            }
        });
```

Method(if you need it)

```
public void updateSavingsView(int savings){

        TextView savingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saverTextView);
        savingsTextView.setText("Save " + savings + "% per month");

        TextView monthlySavings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savingsMoney);
        if(savings == 0 || Integer.parseInt(income.getText().toString()) == 0 ) {
            monthlySavings.setText("0");
        }
        else{

            monthlySavings.setText(Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(income.getText().toString()) * savings) / 100));
        }
```

So the problem is that when I run program without if statement I have an error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" . It is because it reads empty string and want to parse it. Then I add if statement to avoid this problem but it doesn't work.
And my question is. How I can rewrite this listener to avoid these problems and to store correct data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code inside the positive listener

```
    Button mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReportActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_for_percent , null);
                final EditText savingsDialog = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.percentEditText);
                mBuilder.setView(mView)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.done, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    SharedPreferences savings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savings.edit();
                    editor.putString("percent", savingsDialog.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();

                    updateSavingsView(Integer.parseInt(savingsDialog.getText().toString()));
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
             }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I can't beacuse my EditText savingsDialog is outside and it gives me error that I should declare it final

Comment: then declare it final.. no problem. do it

Comment: Yeah it works. I thought that iw will be not so obvious answer. I avoid finals.. But here is only one way